# How are UDP messages received, exactly?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

So anywhere I read anything about `UDP`, people say this;

1. Messages can be received out of order
2. It's possible a message never arrives at all

The first one isn't clear to me. This is what can happen with `TCP`:

I send `1234`, client receives `12` and then `34`

So no problem; just prepend the message length and it's all good. After all, an integer is always 4 bytes, so even if the client receives the prepended length in 2 goes, it will know to keep reading until it has at least 4 bytes to know the msg length.

Anyway, back to `UDP`, what's the deal now when people say '*packages can be received out of order*'?

```
A) Send `1234`, client receives `34` and then `12`
B) Send `1234` and `5678`, client receives `5678` and then `1234`
```

If it's A, I don't see how I can make UDP work for me at all. How would the client ever know what's what?

Comment: It's B. You get a datagram or not.

Comment: Please google "TCP vs UDP" and you will find many articles which will help you

Comment: @falsetru So in UDP, it is entirely impossible for 1 message to be received in multiple segments regardless of msg size? Or can they be multiple segments, but are those guaranteed to be correctly ordered?

Comment: @natli, You cannot send a datagram that exceed 65535 bytes (UDP length field is 2 byte). You should split it if it exceed 65535 bytes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how a network protocol works.

Comment: Out of order means out of order. No explanation required. @falsetru The maximum payload of an IPv4 UDP datagram is 65507 bytes, because of the UDP and IP packet header overheads, but the maximum practical size is determined by the path MTU, which is around 1200 bytes, and by the propensity of routers to split packets above 576 bytes. The practical maximum is generally accepted to be 534 bytes.

Comment: @bmargulies Really? What is and what isn't off-topic on this site is vague at best... it's a very specific question and clearly relates to programming (how can I parse data if I don't know if a message can be received in segments?) but thanks for the downvotes, whoever that were!

Comment: But a UDP message *can't* be received in segments, so the programming problem you refer to doesn't exist.

Comment: @EJP And everyone is born with this knowledge? If I already knew the answer to the question, I wouldn't be asking. Saying that a question is off-topic because the answer is, is a little odd. I'm fairly sure there will be other programmers wondering about the same thing, especially if moving from TCP to UDP. So no, I don't agree with this being off topic ór the downvotes.

Comment: The fAQ will tell you that this site is for _programming_ questions. This isn't a programing question, it's a network protocol question. In several of our opinions, that is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely possible that a network has many paths to reach a given point, so one of the datagram could take one route to reach the other end, another packet could take another path. Given this, the last packet sent could arrive before another packet. UDP takes no measures to correct this, as there's no notion of a connection, and in-order delivery.

At this points it depends on how you send your data. For UDP, each send() or similar call sends one UDP datagram, and recv() receives one datagram. A datagrams can be reordered with respect to other datagrams, or disappear entirely. Data cannot be reordered or dropped within a datagram, you either receive exactly the message that was sent, or you don't receive it at all.

If you need datagrams/messages to arrive in order, you need to add a sequence number to your packets, queue and reorder them at the receiving end.

Comment: `Data cannot be reordered or dropped within a datagram` and there's the answer to my question. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

The usual metaphore is:

- TCP is a *telephone conversation*: words arrive in the *same order* as they were spoken
- UDP is sending a *series of letters by mail*: the letters *may get lost*, may arrive, and can *arrive in any order*.

TCP also involves a *connection* : if the telephone line is disrupted by a thunderstorm, the connection breaks, and has to be built up again. (you need to dial again)

UDP is *connectionless* and *unreliable*: if the mailman is hit by a truck, some letters may be lost. Some letters could also be picked up and delivered by other mailmen. Letters can even be dropped on the floor if your mailbox is full, and even without any reason.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer but this doesn't actually answer my question so I'm picking the other one.